# Boost.Regex. Ошибка при компиляции

Tags: gcc, boost, c++11

Здравствуйте. Я пытаюсь скампилировать проект с использование Boost.Regex. При компиляции получаю такие ошибки:

```
/home/devnikor/Qt Projects/build-Library-Desktop-Debug/Library.o:-1: In function `bool boost::regex_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string>, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string> > >, char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string>, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string>, boost::match_results<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string>, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string> > > >&, boost::basic_regex<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > > const&, boost::regex_constants::_match_flags)':
/usr/include/boost/regex/v4/regex_match.hpp:50: error: undefined reference to `boost::re_detail::perl_matcher<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string>, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string> > >, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::match()'
/usr/include/boost/regex/v4/basic_regex.hpp:382: error: undefined reference to `boost::basic_regex<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::do_assign(char const*, char const*, unsigned int)'
/usr/include/boost/regex/v4/perl_matcher.hpp:374: error: undefined reference to `boost::re_detail::perl_matcher<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string>, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string> > >, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::construct_init(boost::basic_regex<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > > const&, boost::regex_constants::_match_flags)'
:-1: error: collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Компилирую при помощи GCC 4.8 в Qt Creator 2.7.
Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: а при компиляции добавили соответствующие библиотеки? думаю скорее всего `-lboost_regex-mt`

Comment: добавил этот параметр - ничего не изменилось

Comment: параметры нужно добавлять правильно. просто так добавить - ничего не получится.

Comment: Добавил так: QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -lboost_regex-mt

Comment: все таки Вам нужно задать опции линковщика, а не компилятора. Я бы добавил в pro файл что то вида

LIBS += -lboost_regex-mt

Comment: Сработало LIBS += -lboost_regex. Спасибо за помощь. Вы хоть в ответе это напишите, я вам плюсик поставлю :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

все таки Вам нужно задать опции линковщика, а не компилятора. Я бы добавил в pro файл что то вида

```
LIBS += -lboost_regex-mt
```

или так

```
LIBS += -lboost_regex
```

Первая для многопоточных программ (если я правильно помню).

Некоторые библиотеки в бусте требуют линковки. А некоторые только заголовки (обычно это указывается).

Comment: хотел ещё спросить, линковщин сам не может найти нужные библиотеки как, например в Visual Studio, где я просто указывал папку со всеми бустовскими библиотеками

Comment: линковщик - нет. Обычно этим занимаются системы сборки, которые генерируют правильные makefile. Часто используют в комбинации с pkg-config, который умеет выдать "правильный набор ключей для компилятора, что бы подключить какой-то функционал. В бусте вроде были свои подсистемы.

Comment: @ProkletyiPirat, а не подскажете что и как добавить?